# Variável para chamar onde buscar no banco de dados!

Tags: php

Alguém sabe se é possível eu fazer uma busca no banco de dados usando uma variável como o nome de onde buscar no banco, tipo como segue:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE $turma = '$grupo'");
```

Onde a variável `$turma` seria definida pelo usuário.

Comment: O que vai conter na variável `$turma`? É nome da coluna na tabela ?

Comment: @wmsouza sim, na variável `$turma` estaria o nome da coluna na tabela!

Comment: Fora o enorme problema de segurança, está tendo algum problema?

Comment: Seu código parece funcionar, não entendi qual sua pergunta.

Comment: @Maniero eu estava tendo um problema sim, porém era a posição do meu form, revendo o código eu vi esse erro meu, agora deu certo. Eu sou novo no SQL, essa foi a forma que aprendi no curso, você me indicaria algum material ou video aula pra aprender melhor sobre essa questão de segurança e deixar o site mais seguro?

Comment: @Francisco Era um problema com o FORM, ai o código não estava rodando, e como não percebi achei que fosse na consulta, muito obrigado!

Comment: Se quer uma indicação de curso sugiro esse para não usar mais o `mysqli`: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etRFu_eJ3vU&list=PLbXvLovKLUIkE78UNFE8UpfOtoDlrpQec

Comment: @LaércioLopes muito obrigado, eu vou pesquisar sobre PDO, tinha ouvido falar sobre, mas ainda não tive como pesquisar mais a fundo, vou fazer isso!

Comment: Tem as videoaulas aí no link do youtube que coloquei

Comment: Sim, vou usar elas, parecem ser muito boas, muito obrigado!